# OIDC1.0 SLO not working in Spring Authorization Server

Tags: spring-security, openid-connect

I have one Spring Boot application using Spring Authorization Server 3.1.2. It is using OAuth2 and OIDC1.0 for Authentication. I have two clients one is the order-client ,and the other is product-client.SSO is working fine. But logout is not working. I can logout from order-client successfully.

The question is the OP doesn't triggle the others RP's logout. I found nowhere to config Front-Channel Logout and Back-Channel Logout properties .

I expect the others RP'logout works fine.

Comment: ok， the Spring Authorization Server still not supported 
OpenID Connect Front-Channel Logout #1201
OpenID Connect Back-Channel Logout #1200

Answer (score 0):

##### RP initiated logout

It is implemented in Spring OAuth2 clients and Spring authorization server. You just need to set the following in your clients `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessHandler(new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository)));
```

This will terminate the user session on the authorization server when he logs out from one of the clients.

##### Back-Channel Logout

This was added only [very recently](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/12570) to the codebase and I'm not sure it was released yet. So you might have to wait until next Spring Security & Boot releases to have a user session automatically closed on all clients when this user logs out somewhere.

Comment: Thanks  for your help, I will always pay attention to the continuous changes of this project.